# try-catch-finally formatexception

Tags: c#, datetime, try-catch-finally

I am trying to capture input data from a Textbox by converting it to `DateTime` format

```
string yy = string.Format("{0:T}", textBox1.Text);
```

I wish to use `Try-Catch-Finally` to produce an `Systm.FormatException` error and display it  in another text box

```
try 
{
 DateTime XF = Convert.ToDateTime(yy); 
}
 catch (FormatException)    
       { 
       textBox5.Text = "incorrect time"; 
       }
   finally 
          {
           DateTime XF = Convert.ToDateTime(yy); 
           textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(XF.Hour + XF.Minute + XF.Second); 
          }
```

How should i go around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an exception to do this, it'd be better to use `DateTime.TryParse`. This will return a simple `true` or `false` if it can be converted into a date.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

```
DateTime xf;
bool canBeConverted = DateTime.TryParse(yy, out xf);
if (!canBeConverted) { textBox5.Text = "incorrect time"; }
```

Comment: I doubt that it actually swallows any exceptions. Using ILSpy, I found _no_ exceptions being catched inside the `TryParse` functions or their called functions.

Comment: @UweKeim You are right, the whole point of TryParse is that no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()` if you're not sure if the format is correct. There's no need for exceptions, which are slow and less clear.

```
string dateString;
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, result))
{
    // it's a recognized as a DateTime
}
else
{
    // it's not recognized as a DateTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `DateTime.TryParseExact or DateTime.TryParse Method`.

Eg.:

```
    string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008";
string format = "ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    textBox5.Text = "correct time";
}
    else
      textBox5.Text = "incorrect time";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateTime.TryParse()` method.